# Use of Repeater asp.net with datatable Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I'm new to ASP.NET techonology and I'm trying to use datatable Jquery with a repeater.

But it doesn't work with the value inside the table. It work with just the head (see below). These data come from a database.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Model2">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="table_id">
            <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>ip</th>
            <th>askit</th>
        </tr>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("Li_Id")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Li_ip")%> </td>
            <td><%# Eval("Li_nom_askit")%> </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </ItemTemplate>

         <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And here it's what I get

[Screen of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgDuy.png)

So for example the line with id '594' is not in the datable that I have create.
I try to use a ListView but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a separate tbody around each row.  Move the opening tbody tag to the end of the header template and the closing tbody tag to the beginning of the footer template.

(I'm assuming you're referring to the datatables.net jQuery plugin.)

Comment: You're welcome.  If you'd be so kind as to accept the answer, I'd appreciate it!